# how to convert curl into php cURL

Tags: php, curl

I have referenced and tried suggestions from previous stackoverflow questions to try and convert this type of CURL request to php but failed: Bad request returned. I have also read up on it and tried the following as well as other attempts:
This type of request works:

```
$ curl -X POST \
  -u f98b80bd3aa9dd8:748b2a74-cf59-4afb-facf-b79f3ba51e46 \
  -H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
  -d '{"hash": "fa814e37ad092518b0b22ed1f21c8bac4daed663433abba01e369399522279e6"}'
  https://api-prod.stamp.com/stamps
```

My clearest attempts:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-prod.stamp.com/stamps');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'f98b80bd3aa9dd8:748b2a74-cf59-4afb-facf-b79f3ba51e46');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"hash":"fa814e37ad092518b0b22ed1f21c8bac4daed663433abba01e369399522279e6"}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
```

Also tried:

```
$url = 'https://api-prod.stamp.com/stamps';
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('content-type: application/json'));
$json = json_encode('{f98b80bd3aa9dd8:748b2a74-cf59-4afb-facf-b79f3ba51e46"}');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Updated on suggestion from cBroe, improved but still not right: Update

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-prod.stamp.com/stamps');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERNAME, 'f98b80bd3aa9dd8');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '748b2a74-cf59-4afb-facf-b79f3ba51e46');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"hash":"fa814e37ad092518b0b22ed1f21c8bac4daed663433abba01e369399522279e6"}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: your second attempt should be fine. what's wrong with that ?

Comment: @AlexandrKapustin This comes back: {"error": "Authentication Required", "result": null} I'm trying to get round this Cull approach by using a Node.js script. Sorry for late reply. If delete this soon if I can't find a solution. It must be some minor syntax miss-match.